# Obtener diferencia de una consulta de dos tablas (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buen día, en cada nube de puntos existen áreas de trabajo (Ingenieria, Seguridad, Mantenimiento, etc). Busco poder agregar más áreas a la nube seleccionada dándole como opción al cliente de identificarlas en un select y agregarlas en el botón. **La problemática** es que no busco como obtener las áreas no existentes en relación a la nube para posibilitar la selección en el multi-select.  [image: Se observa en la imagen las áreas ya relacionadas con la nube (Tabla). Deseo recuperar el query de las no relacionadas para asignarlas al multi-select].

**Existe las tabla áreas y la tabla area_clouds.**
Se entiende que por medio de la tabla area_clouds recupero las areas relacionadas con la nube.
Busco obtener de la tabla areas toda aquella que no ha sido seleccionada.

*EJEMPLO*
Si en la tabla areas existe Seguridad, Mantenimiento y Soporte y en la tabla area_clouds solo tengo Seguridad, deseo obtener entonces *Mantenimiento y Soporte* como diferencia.

```
$getAreas = DB::table('areas as a') //Ingreso a la tabla areas para obtener toda la lista 
   ->select('a.id', 'a.name', 'a.organization_id') //Selecciono los campos necesarios 
   ->leftjoin('area_clouds as b', 'b.area_id', '=', 'a.id') //Intento hacer uso de la relación con la segunda tabla
   ->where('a.organization_id', '=', $idOrganization) //Limitante para obtener las areas dependiendo de la organizacion
//Aqui debe de ir una consulta para obtener la diferencia un ejemplo seria el Except pero no se hacerlo.
   ->get();
```

En el controlador de cloud tengo:

```
 public function areaCloud()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AreaCloud');
    }
```

y en area_clouds tengo:

```
 public function cloud()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cloud');
    }
```

y en el modelo area tengo esto:

```
  public function areaCloud()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AreaCloud');
    }
```

Leyendo he encontrado opciones como Except o Wherenull para obtener las diferencias entre tablas pero no logro ejecutar mi objetivo con éxito, espero puedan apoyarme

Comment: Veo que es una relación de uno a muchos, ¿tienes las relaciones definidas en los modelos?

Comment: Si, en los modelos tengo las relaciones definidas.

Comment: Agrega la definición de tus relaciones a tu pregunta por favor para poder publicar mi respuesta

Comment: Pero si tienes un modelo Area? por que de ahi es necesaria la relación que usaremos dada tu pregunta

Comment: Si, disculpa, ya agregué mis tres modelos, debo modificar algo entre ambos? como debo aplicar tu doesntHave?

Answer (score 1):

**Opción 1**

La consulta que muestras es técnicamente correcta, el problema es que al momento te mostraría areas tengan o no tengan al menos un renglón relacionado con area_clouds, lo que puedes hacer es agregar al final este filtro para sacar el resultado esperado:

```
WHERE area_clouds.area_id IS NULL;
```

**Opción 2**

Sin embargo puedes construir una subconsulta con [*subconsulta con `WHERE NOT EXISTS`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) con una estructura similar a esta:

```
SELECT areas.name
FROM areas
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM area_clouds 
                 WHERE areas.id = area_clouds.area_id);
```

Donde le indiquemos que necesitamos todos los registros de la tabla areas pero donde no exista la relación dada entre la llave primaria de (areas) con un renglón de (area_clouds) con una llave foránea.

Si bien podemos componer esta consulta a nivel del query builder, como propongo al inicio en el punto 1 o incluso estructurando la antes mencionada, en estos casos y dado que si tienes las relaciones de Eloquent definidas entonces lo mas simple es hacer esto:

```
$query = Area::doesntHave('areaCloud')
            ->whereOrganizationId($idOrganization)
            ->first();
```

Lo que hacemos es indicarle que filtraremos del modelo Area aquellos registros que no tengan al menos una relación en relación con ayuda del método [doesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

Te resta a ti además verificar que tus tablas sigan las [convenciones de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) y en caso de no ser así entonces debes agregar los [parámetros extra a tus relaciones que aquí puedes leer a detalle](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Ya anexé como tengo las relaciones, ¿Funciona para realizarla con tu segundo método? lo he agregado pero sigue sin funcionar, ¿Debo modificar algo en mis modelos?

Comment: Editaré mi respuesta pues mi hicieron falta algunos detalles @OscarFabianRomeroHdez espera

Comment: Te agregué mis tres modelos, me confirmas si debo modificar algo entre ellos

Comment: Listo ya edité, debes revisar a detalle el apartado de los parámetros extra que debes pasar en tus relaciones de ser necesario, para eso checa el último enlace propuesto; por lo demás ya te debe funcionar @OscarFabianRomeroHdez

Comment: Tuviste toda la razón mi estimado sin embargo mi lógica en la explicación fue mala, debido que efectivamente me devuelve las áreas no vinculadas de acuerdo a $idOrganization. El detalle es que debería de ser por la nube (Recuperar las areas no seleccionadas de acuerdo a la nube)

Comment: Quieres filtrar por el ID de la nube entonces @OscarFabianRomeroHdez

Comment: Si me aclaras ese punto entonces edito la respuesta

Comment: Si, así es, de acuerdo a la nube presenta las áreas que también corresponde a la organización, es decir, la organización tiene 3 áreas, de las cuales en una nube tal ves utilice 2 pero la otra solo 1. ¿Me entiendes? Requiero obtener esa restante por nube seleccionada